# load Gmagick class from wrong namespace

Tags: php, silex, gmagick

i want to work with Gmagick i wrote this code 
`$image = new \Gmagick();
$image->readimage($file);`
, and i have this error : [Attempted to load class "Gmagick" from the global namespace.
Did you forget a "use" statement?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G854J.jpg)

Comment: have you installed gmagick?

Comment: how? to install it

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/gmagick.installation.php - `sudo pecl install gmagick`